# Selenium Actions class dragAndDrop process get stuck when try to element drop

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, drag-and-drop, action

I‘m trying to do drag and drop scenario in a list of elements.Currently I’m using Actions class to do the job, but it’s hang the process when trying to drop the element to the target position.

I’ve tried following solutions so far,

1. dragAndDrop(source,target)
2. clickAndHold(source) , release(target) - here release not happened until manually do the mouse movement.
3. Javascripts dragAndDrops not worked in the application
4. Robot class - not getting the exact element position in the local machine plus in the servers.

As my guess best way to do this from actions class , Any solution for doing  clickAndHold and once release function called do the mouseMovement from automation.It will hang the process inside the release function. And moveToElement will not work as well.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.